# How do I get a compiled SQL query from a SQLAlchemy expression if params is a dict?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, bind-variables

I have this code (using sqlalchemy):

```
 session = self._new_session(database_id=dbname)
 with session.begin():
    result_proxy = session.execute(sql_query, sql_params)
```

where

```
sql_query = 'select * from t_client where id = :id'
sql_params = {'id': 5131}
```

How may I see the actual query before executing without using regular expression? I mean something like this:

```
select * from t_client where id = 5131
```

Comment: Output the two variables.  Or mail them to yourself.  You'll have to do some minor editing to get a useable sql command but it might be good enough.

Comment: thanks, I understand it. But how to get the useable sql query with params already in? I mean if there is the easier way to get this 'select * from t_client where id = 5131' from that 'query = 'select * from t_client where id = :id'
query_params = {'id': 5131}' rather than use regex?

Comment: :\w+ i may use this, but maybe I can get result query from sa?

Comment: An important thing to note is that the query `select * from t_client where id = :id` is at no point converted to `select * from t_client where id = 5131`. Instead, the parameters are sent separately as part of the underlying RDBMS-specific protocol in order to mitigate SQL injection attacks.

Comment: oh, thanks for answer! 'the parameters are sent separately' was the main thing I was interested in.